# detox init -r jest is throwing error on Linux ubuntu. Any alternative commands for it

Tags: linux, react-native, ubuntu-18.04, detox

detox init -r jest

above command is throwing error on my local project.

init: No such file or directory
jest: No such file or directory

I have checked in my package.json, jest is configured.

my system environment:

Linux Ubuntu 18.4

Kindly help/suggest if there are any other ways to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue, so closing it.

> > My project paths are changed and applied few changes according to the following documentation.

https://github.com/wix/Detox

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command resolved it for me:

> $ npx detox init

And that's it